# Making flexbox column use the available width

Tags: css, flexbox

There is a container which has a flexible width and a number of fluid blocks inside it. My goal is to use all available space from left to right inside this container.

Flexbox with flex-direction "column" suits nearly perfectly for my scenario. 
I have one issue with it: *unless I specify the heights of the container, the inner blocks align themselves into 1  single column* (when I expect them to form several columns).

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kopgjpsp/1/

```
css

    .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    max-width: 600px;
    /*max-height: 100px -- I am trying to avoid this*/
}

.box .fluid_block {
    max-width: 250px;
}

.fluid_block .title {
    padding-right: 30px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.fluid_block .value {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="fluid_block">
        <div class="title">Fluid block 1</div> 
        <div class="value">some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fluid_block">
        <div class="title">Fluid block 2</div> 
        <div class="value">some content some content some content</div>
    </div>
        <div class="fluid_block">
        <div class="title">Fluid block 3</div> 
        <div class="value">some content some content some content some content</div>
    </div>
        <div class="fluid_block">
        <div class="title">Fluid block 3</div> 
        <div class="value">some content some content some content some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The solution I see at the moment is to calculate width with JS and set it, however, it is ugly and expensive, so I would like to avoid it if i can.

I would appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Removing "wrap" has the same effect as adding the unwanted max-height. If you have the wrap for some reason that's not obvious to me at the moment, sorry, then you can add "flex-grow:1" instead and keep the "wrap", that still has the same effect as adding the absolute max-height. 
If all else fails, set max-height to 0px; hope this helps :-)